# Weblogic 12C External properties file not loading

Tags: weblogic12c

I'm not finding a solution for external file configuration in weblogic 12c. log4j.xml,products.properties and other property files are there in one directory, I need to load all these directory files. if create a jar file and keep it in lib folder its working fine.

1.I tried to configure by keeping all properties and `log4j.xml` files in domain directory.

2. kept the directory in domain/config folder and changed setDomainEnv.sh ex:`EXT_POST_CLASSPATH="${EXT_POST_CLASSPATH};${DOMAIN_HOME}/config/" export EXT_POST_CLASSPATH`

3.Tried CLASSPATH change `CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}/home/weblogic/weblogic122130/middleware/domain/"`

4.`JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS}-DpropFileLocation =/home/weblogic/weblogic122130/middleware/domain/config/"`

none of them solved the weblogic 12c configuration problem.

<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <9d65409c-86b2-4355-81a4-6aee55503056-00000008> <1568091067885> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] >  (Logger.java:24)
    at com.iexceed.appzillon.logging.LoggerFactory.getRestServicesLogger(LoggerFactory.java:61)
    at com.iexceed.appzillon.startup.AppzillonRestWSStartup.(AppzillonRestWSStartup.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:252)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.createInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:297)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.createInstance(WebAppServletContext.java:4256)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.createInstance(WebAppServletContext.java:4244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListener(EventsManager.java:518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListeners(EventsManager.java:154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListeners(EventsManager.java:97)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1919)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3101)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1843)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:884)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:274)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:507)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:53)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:202)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:52)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:702)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:381)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:786)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)

> <10 Sep, 2019 10:21:07,887 AM IST>     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <9d65409c-86b2-4355-81a4-6aee55503056-00000008> <1568091067887> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] >

Comment: Can you try to add -Dlog4j.configuration=... to your java options ?

Comment: not only log4j.xml file, property files also need to be picked up from the directory.

Comment: post complete error message and stack trace from weblogic server's log plz.